# How to prevent Markdown from wrapping the generated HTML in a <p> element?

Tags: javascript, markdown

**Update:** The bounty is for a solution using the “marked” library.

---

This Markdown code:

```
*foo*
```

will produce this HTML code:

```
<p><em>foo</em></p>
```

**Live demo:** https://jsbin.com/luganot/edit?js,console

However, I'm already injecting the generated HTML code into an inline context, like so:

```
<p> text [inject generated HTML here] text </p>
```

so I don't want the `<p>` element to wrap around the generated HTML code. I just want the `*` delimiters to be converted to an `<em>`, element, and so on.

Is there a way to tell the Markdown converter to not produce the `<p>` wrapper? Currently, I'm doing a `.slice(3,-4)` on the generated HTML string, which does remove the `<p>`, and `</p>` tags, but this is obviously not a solution I'd like to keep for the long-term.

Comment: Do you need any attribute on your outer `<p>` tag? Can't you just render the Markdown output without the wrapper? Otherwise, just wrap it in a plain `<div>` [further styled] so you won't have any nesting issues.

Comment: Why not just remove the `<p>` from your HTML if its always injected ?

Comment: @ManseUK What do you mean? Remove it from the Markdown-generated string?

Comment: @moonwave99 Render the Markdown output without the wrapper? What does that mean? The Markdown output is a HTML string which contains the `<p>` wrapper.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas What I mean is why have the `<p>` in your HTML in the first place ? if showdown adds its everytime ... so .. change `<p> text [inject generated HTML here] text </p>` to `text [inject generated HTML here] text`

Comment: @ManseUK I'm adding the Markdown generated HTML in **inline-context**, i.e. there is text before, and after. This text is not part of the string that is passed to Markdown.

Comment: @ManseUK I can't do that because then the outer text would not be rendered in the same line as the Markdown generated stuff. I need it to all be in the same line.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm struggling with the same

Comment: @JavisPerez See the accepted answer.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thank you! that's a great solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can skip the block-lexing part and use inlineLexer instead.

```
html = marked.inlineLexer(markdown, [], options);

//example
marked.inlineLexer('*foo*', []) // will output '<em>foo</em>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Would using jQuery be an option? This would work in case:

```
var $text = $(new Showdown.converter().makeHtml( '*foo*' ) );
console.log( $text.html() );
```

Comment: That's a creative approach. However, it does perform a parsing/serialization process, and there is no guarantee that the resulting HTML string will be the same string as the initial string without the `<p>` wrapper (as the parsing/serialization is relayed to the browser, and different browsers may produce different results). I still prefer my `slice` approach.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for a solution for this too when I found this SO thread. I didn't find any good solution yet here so I've written my own.

```
var markdown = new Showdown.converter().makeHtml( '*foo*' );
console.log(markdown.replace(/^<p>|<\/p>$/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [commonmark standard](http://commonmark.org/), there isn't an official way to remove unwanted elements from the markup that markdown would otherwise generate. [In 2014 I asked about the possibility of an inline mode](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/inline-markdown-vs-block-markdown/357), but that didn't really generate much activity and I never followed up with it to make it a reality.

With that said, the simplest solution I know of to sanitize markdown is to run it through a whitelist as a post-processing step.

Simply stripping `<p>` tags probably isn't enough because it would be relatively easy to accidentally add `#` characters and end up with stray `h1-6` tags, or have inline `<div>` elements which aren't allowed in `<p>` elements.

Whitelisting is pretty straightforward in JS as long as you're in a browser context or using a similar DOM API.

This example takes the output from `marked` and generates a document fragment. The nodes in the fragment are then filtered based on whether they're [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#phrasing-content) (which are the only nodes that `<p>` elements may contain). After filtering, the resultant nodes are then returned so that they may be used in the DOM.

```js
const phrasingContent = [
  '#text', 'a', 'abbr', 'area', 'audio', 'b', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'br', 'button',
  'canvas', 'cite', 'code', 'data', 'datalist', 'del', 'dfn', 'em', 'embed',
  'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'input', 'ins', 'kbd', 'keygen', 'label', 'map', 'mark',
  'math', 'meter', 'noscript', 'object', 'output', 'picture', 'progress', 'q',
  'ruby', 's', 'samp', 'script', 'select', 'small', 'span', 'strong', 'sub',
  'sup', 'svg', 'template', 'textarea', 'time', 'u', 'var', 'video', 'wbr'
]

function sanitize(text) {
  const t = document.createElement('template')
  t.innerHTML = text
  whitelist(t.content, phrasingContent)
  return t.content
}

function whitelist(parent, names) {
  for (const node of parent.childNodes) {
    whitelist(node, names)
  
    if (!names.includes(node.nodeName.toLowerCase())) {
      unwrap(node)
    }
  }
}

function unwrap(node) {
  const parent = node.parentNode
  while (node.firstChild) {
    parent.insertBefore(node.firstChild, node)
  }
  parent.removeChild(node)
}

function empty(node) {
  while (node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild)
  }
}

const form = document.querySelector('form')
const input = document.querySelector('textarea')
const output = document.querySelector('output')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  empty(output)
  
  output.appendChild(sanitize(marked(input.value)))
}, false)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <textarea name="input" cols="30" rows="10">*foo*</textarea>
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>

<p> text <output></output> text </p>
```

Of course, all of this assumes a browser environment, and that whitelisting may be handled after the input is processed through the `marked` library.

Comment: I’ve come up with an alternative to `.slice(3, -4)`. This: `marked(\`<div>${source}</div>\`).match(/^<div>(.*)<\/div>$/)[1]`; [demo](https://jsbin.com/luganot/edit?js,console). It may seem a bit convoluted, but I think it’s pretty reliable. I can put it in an `inline_marked` helper function.